# Net::HTTP to Newrelic returns 404, but curl returns 200

Tags: ruby, https, net-http

I am currently using Ruby's Net::HTTP library to query a Newrelic endpoint. Recently, these queries have started returning 404. I tested my exact query through curl - in the hopes of perhaps getting a more detailed error message back - but the query through curl actually returns a 200 with the expected data. So the query does work, and I am sort of at a loss as to why Net::HTTP would be returning a 404 at this point.

Here are some code snippets of what I have so far, and if anyone can offer any suggestions of further things to try, that would be much appreciated!

**Environment**:

- JRuby 1.7.26 (so Ruby 1.9.3p551)
- Rails 3.2.21

**Ruby code**:

```
uri = URI('https://NEWRELIC_HOST/PATH/ACCOUNT_ID/query')
parameters = { :nrql => NRQL_QUERY_STRING }
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(parameters)

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.to_s)
request['X-Query-Key'] = NEWRELIC_QUERY_KEY

Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, {:use_ssl => true}) do |http|
    response = http.request(request)
end
```

This returns me a 404 error code every time. I have tried it against a couple valid Newrelic endpoints/accounts and every time is a 404 error.

**CURL code**:

Now if I take that same request, and punt it to curl on the command line, there are no issues, I get a 200 with all data returned properly:

```
curl -H "X-Query-Key: NEWRELIC_QUERY_KEY" https://NEWRELIC_HOST/PATH/ACCOUNT_ID/query?NRQL_QUERY_STRING
```

Comment: does it work for other endpoints than newrelic?

Comment: If you have access to the server logs, the answer may be there

Comment: @philipp Yes we use it in a few places to retrieve data, and in fact we use Net::HTTP to retrieve other forms of data from Newrelic and those ones are all working fine - they all follow the same format.

Comment: @JohnHascall good idea, I will see if I can get access to the newrelic server logs

Comment: Rather than use Net::HTTP, use one of the many [Ruby HTTP clients](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients). They'll make it easier for you. Net::HTTP is good if you're creating a new server type, but for web stuff there are plenty of well-written and tested wheels.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

```
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.to_s)
```

to

```
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
```

Comment: Thanks! You're right - oddly enough I also stumbled across that and it does work! However now I am just trying to understand why it broke... We have used uri.to_s in all our Net::HTTP calls and it has always worked - and in fact still works for ALL our other API calls - and there are a lot of them.

Comment: Also for what it is worth, Newrelic tech support was able to reproduce our problem using our code - and was able to fix it by simply using `Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)` - but that actually causes an error elsewhere for us which I am currently also trying to trace down. We will likely end up changing all spots to use `uri.request_uri`, but I would also really love to understand why this happened :)